# Storing model coefficients in a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression, store

This seems like a very basic problem, but I have not been able to find a solution. I essentially wish to run a linear regression in a for loop and store the model coefficients (and standard errors if possible) for each iteration in an csv file.

For reference, I am running Fama-MacBeth regressions on macroeconomic "shocks," (the residuals of macroeconomic factors regressed on their lagged values).

My code for the loop is as follows

```
for (i in 7:69){
  model <- lm(data = data, data[[i]]~TM2R+IPR+InfR+UnR+OilR)
  #Model coefficients
  print(model$coefficients)
  #Standard Errors in regression results
  model$vcov <- vcovHC(model, type = "HC1") 
  print(model$vcov)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `broom` package to transform the output from `lm()` to a data frame, then append the results from `vconvHC()` to it.

Finally, you export as csv.

```r
library(broom)
library(sandwich)

for (i in 7:69){
  model_name  <- paste0("model_", i, ".csv")
  
  model_i <- lm(data = data, data[[i]]~TM2R+IPR+InfR+UnR+OilR)
  tidy_model <- tidy(model_i)
  tidy_model$vcov <- vcovHC(model_i, type = "HC1")
  
  write.csv(tidy_model, file = model_name)
}
```